# SQL - Subtracting Milliseconds from Current Date Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query that will let me get records entered between now and a some number of minutes in the past. I have the number of minutes as milliseconds. So, I'm trying to write a SQL query that will let me get those records.

I see a [DateAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function. However, I don't see a function to Subtract some time from a date. From a pseduo-code perspective, I'm trying to do this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
  CreatedAt > (GetUtcDate() - milliseconds)
```

How do I get records from `MyTable` that have happened within some past window of time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try using [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in millisecond mode:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CreatedAt > DATEADD(ms, -60000, GETDATE());  -- 60000 ms = 1 minute
```

This would return all records which were created within one minute of the current date and time.

Answer (score 1):

The function you want is [DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
SELECT {YourColumns}
FROM MyTable MT
WHERE CreatedAt > DATEADD(millisecond,{value},GETUTCDATE());
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite its name, the `DATEADD` function is also the "DATESUBTRACT" function that you're looking for. (Intentionally double-quoted as quasi-code.)

The first parameter defines the sorts of units you're adding or subtracting, i.e. `HOUR`, `DAY`, `WEEK`, etc., or, in your case, `MILLISECOND`. In the second parameter, if you want to add time, you enter a positive number. If you want to subtract time, as you do here, enter a negative number of units.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to interact with date and time in SQL is to use specific date and time functions rather than adding dates as you would add numbers.

In this case the function you are looking for is [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), using it your cord should change like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE CreatedAt > DATEADD(ms, -milliseconds, GetUtcDate())
```